# LARAVEL - Undefined variable: imageName

Tags: laravel, image

Seeking for your help again. I'm having trouble on uploading multiple images. I'm getting this error Undefined variable: imageName. Please help.

Controller:

```
            if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            $imageName =  $request->image->store('public');
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('image2')){
              $imageName2 =  $request->image2->store('public');
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('image3')){
              $imageName3 =  $request->image3->store('public');
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('image4')){
              $imageName4 =  $request->image4->store('public');
            }

            if ($request->hasFile('image5')){
            $imageName5 =  $request->image5->store('public');
            }

             $post = new post;

          $post->image = $imageName;
          $post->image2 = $imageName2;
          $post->image3 = $imageName3;
          $post->image4 = $imageName4;
          $post->image5 = $imageName5;
```

Need your help please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing a variable you need to declare it first. So, before all your if conditions, declare them like this:

```
$imageName = $imageName2 = $imageName3 = ... = null;

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
.
.
```